# How many students need to be checked to be 90% sure they got a grade of 70..80?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Can you help me on some question i'm stuck on?

**Let X be a random variable of the average grade of the students in some course.**

**`E[X] = 75`**

**`Var[X] = 25`**

**What's the number of students that need to be checked in order to assure in at least 90% that their average grade is between 70 and 80?**

Here's what i've done:

$P(70<X<80) < P(|X-75|<5) = 1-P(|X-75|>=5) >= 0.9$ *(according to Chebyshev)*

Now let $5=a*s$ (s = standard deviation , a is a parameter). Then we need:

$1-\frac{1}{a^2} = 0.9$

That is $a=\sqrt{10}$

Which means $s=\frac{5}{\sqrt{10}}$

Which means Variance = $s^2 = 2.5$

So apparently this is wrong because i believe i can't change the variance in the question... Plus, i didn't conclude anything about the number of students...

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: How about this solution:
Since `Var(X)=np(1-p)` then `25=np(1-p)` and so `n=25/p(1-p)`. And we need `n>25/0.9*0.1 = 278`. Problem is this equation holds only for binomial distribution. Can i say the case in the question is binomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a population mean of $\mu=75$ and variance of $\sigma^2=25$. So the distribution of the sample average form a sample of size $n$ also has mean $75$ and has a variance of $\frac{25}{n}$.

So if you decided to use Chebyshev's inequality of the form $\Pr(|Y-E[Y]| \ge t] \le \text{Var}(Y)/t^2$ you would want $ \dfrac{\frac{25}{n}}{5^2} \lt 0.1$, i.e. a sample size of $n \gt 10$.

If you assumed a normal distribution, you would want to look at $ \sqrt{\frac{25}{n}} \Phi^{-1}(0.95) \lt 5$ which would lead to a sample size $n \gt 2.706$.

Comment: Can you please explain why the distribution of the sample average from a sample of size n has a variance of 25/n ?

Comment: Oh i see. It's because `Y=(X1+X2+...+Xn)/n` => `Var(Y)=Var(numerator/denominator)` => `Var(Y)=nVar(X1)/n^2 = 25/n`